# How do I directly talk through a serial port via the keyboard?

Tags: linux, serial-port

I have a hardware controller that I need to communicate to via serial port. How exactly can I communicate with that port using my keyboard as input.

The serial runs on 19200 baudrate, 7 bytesize, and 1 stopbit

Comment: Which `tty` is mapped to your serial port?

Answer (score 1):

Although `minicom(1)` and `screen(1)`, [as proposed by Marco d'Itri](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213172/how-do-i-directly-talk-through-a-serial-port-via-the-keyboard/213210#213210), will both work, neither one lets you talk *directly* to the serial port. Both of them implement their own VT100-style terminal emulation. Since both of them run inside terminals already, this means that they both interpret terminal emulation escape codes to maintain their idea of a virtual screen, then emit new escape codes sent toward the real terminal (e.g. X11 terminal emulator), which in turn interprets them and draws *its* idea of the screen contents in your terminal. `screen` does this because its primary job is not to connect to serial ports but to implement a virtual terminal with different detachable windows. `minicom` does this for no good reason.

For a solution that *directly* talks to the serial port, that is, it simply passes bytes back and forth between your terminal and the serial port, have a look at `cu(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

The sensible way is to use a terminal emulator like `minicom(1)`, which will allow you to easily configure the serial port parameters.

Good old `screen(1)` will work as well, but you will have to manually configure the serial port parameters using `stty(1)`: section 13.2 "Using Exec" of the manual explains how to do this.

Comment: Neither `minicom` nor `screen` connect you *directly* to the serial port as requested by the OP.