# RB5 linux system cannot use ssh to connect V2X with the serial port

Tags: linux, ssh, usb, embedded, sshd

I have a V2X module, and I cannot it to linux/window PC with USB. Then using the command `ssh root@xxx.xxx.1.3`, and entrance the v2x module.`root@autotalks:~#`
However, when i used the RB5, the  `ssh root@xxx.xxx.1.3` command is useless. It will show `sh-4.4# ssh root@xxx.xxx.1.3 ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.1.3 port 22: Connection timed out`

I have search some solution but these solution cannot help me.

https://superuser.com/questions/421004/how-to-fix-warning-about-ecdsa-host-key

[How to Configure OpenSSH Server to connect to an isolated computer's console via a serial port?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/602833/how-to-configure-openssh-server-to-connect-to-an-isolated-computers-console-via)

Can anyone tell me the solution?